# Git filter-branch after a git mv, keep all history in subdirectory

Tags: git, git-clone, git-filter-branch

I have a folder structure like described below, and I'm trying to copy anything which is in *newCode* including history and add it into *newCode2*.

The issue is that we originally did a "*git mv*" on *oldCode* to *newCode*, so now when I do a "*git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter groupB/newCode/ -- --all*" it only gives me the history from after the git mv under *newCode*, and not the history from *oldCode*.

```
repoA.git/
   groupA/ 
       (moved)oldCode/
   groupB/
        newCode/

repoB.git/
   groupC/
       newCode2/
```

Is there a way to get all the history including the history in oldCode?

**Related question:**

Also, if I had changes that were also made to groupB/somefile.cpp as well as groupB/newCode/somefile2.cpp, what happens when I do a filter-branch and blow away the *somefile.cpp* if someone were to do a **git reset**  on that file which is now blown away?

Thanks